# Improving mouth feel of vegan hard boiled yolk

Tags: vegan, hard-boiled-eggs

This recipe is typical of vegan hard boiled egg for salad.
Egg white portion fine. Yolk could use some improvement in mouth feel:

https://www.onegreenplanet.org/vegan-recipe/the-ultimate-genius-vegan-eggs/

2 Tbsp vegan dried instant mashed potatoes, dehydrated flakes or powder
1 tsp nutritional yeast
¼ tsp turmeric (use a little less if you prefer)
¼ tsp kala namak salt
1 tsp potato starch
3 1/3 ounces  hot water
1 tsp vegan margarine or 1 tsp refined pure coconut oil
1 tsp sunflower or canola oil

Some vegan hard boiled egg products coming onto market recently. Mycoprotein being one of their ingredients I don't see getting ahold of.
But maybe lecithin would help?

Any other add ins to make yolk less like mash potato?

I use a commercial yolk flavor to replace kala namak so this is strictly a texture question.

Comment: What's the actual problem? Is it too soft? Too starchy? Describe the result you are getting.

Comment: Less like mash potato more like hard yolk.